# Access entity dynamically based on postgres/ sql db from springboot app based on configuration

Tags: spring-boot, overloading, dynamic-loading, entity-bean

I am building a springboot app which can connect to either sql or postgres db based on configuration. Entity for the two databases are slightly different. Is it possible to create 2 different entity for 2 databases and load them dynamically on startup based on db configuration. Or will I have to maintain 2 code bases. Let me know if more information is required.

I was thinking of creating two different entity classes with only columns that are different and they inherit from same base class. But I don’t know how to load dynamically based on db (property)

Comment: How are they different?

Comment: For postgres data is being stored as jsonb and for sql it’s json

Comment: Shouldn't that be part of the actual dialect instead of your entities? Or you can have a look at https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils which supports JSON types for different databases. Else use profiles and provide an `orm.xml` which contains the mapping for the entities for the specific database and load the one you need based on the profile.